# local file storage deletes content automatically

Tags: c#, windows-8, xml-serialization, windows-runtime

```
    public static async Task SaveFileAsync(string FileName, T data)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(memStream, data);

        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName,
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<T> RestoreFileAsync(string FileName)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
                return result;
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this code to save and retrieve my data and it works fine.

After saving my data in this local file and starting my app, there is no data sometimes.

I'm saving my data as an `.xml` file.

I check the file every time I save and it has the content that been saved.
But sometimes it removes it, I dont know why.

I tried `DataContractJsonSerializer` and still have the same issue.

Comment: Is the file empty or deleted?  **When ** does this happen?  Can you run the app while watching the file?

Comment: no the file is empty, it happens when i restore the data it deletes it, and not all times, only sometimes, and sometimes it holds the data that i saved.

Comment: This is often a locking problem. Does this article help? http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/02/walkthrough-locking-asynchronous-file.html

Answer (score 0):

As Jerry pointed out, this could be a locking problem. It could also be a race condition (we don't see the code where you call these methods, so be sure one can't get called while the other is already running).

One potential area I see is these two lines:

```
storageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName,
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
```

In this code you care creating the file in one step (overwriting if necessary) and then opening the file in another step. You are awaiting, so I don't see anything wrong here, but it makes sense that if you're ending up with an empty file it might be a failure between these two lines. It turns out there is an overload of OpenStreamForWriteAsync that allows you to create the file if it doesn't exist or overwrite it if it does. You could collapse those two steps into one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582148.aspx

Finally (and I don't think this has anything to do with your problem) you can skip the memory stream entirely. DataContractSerializer can write directly to the FileStream just fine. Might as well save yourself a few lines of code and the memory footprint.

I hope that helps. Let us know if you get it figured out.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project. I've added the **await** key word before my calls of SaveFileAsync. I don't call this method in the OnSuspending handler of App.xaml.cs anymore and it works now.